# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:1' pipe:1: Invalid argument

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a bot who can play music with python following a tutorial. He can connect join a voice chat but when I try to make him play music I got that error

[NULL @ 0x55ba7014d420] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:1'
pipe:1: Invalid argument

Here is a part of my code:

```
    async def play (self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMEPG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': 'vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS)as ydl:
           info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
           url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
           source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMEPG_OPTIONS)
           vc.play(source)
```

And I am completely lost I try to find something on the internet but nothing look like my problem. If you need more of the code tell me I will post more.

Comment: Try: `'-vn'` instead of `'vn'`.

Answer (score 0):

'vn' should be '-vn'. Fixed the problem for me.